# How would I make a user database for an iPhone application?

Tags: ios, database

I am relatively new to iOS development and part of the application I'm developing requires a database of users which holds information about each user. Is there a tutorial out there that can show me how to create a database and link it with my iOS app? If not any sort of explanation would work.

Comment: Look into Parse. Their API does all the heavy security and storage and you just build your app around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want a DB to connect to, you'd need 2 things: A DB server and a Webserver to open it through webservices. Since you are new, I'd suggest you set up a LAMP server (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) or a WAMP server (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP).

For WAMP and LAMP, I suggest you install each module separately but there are packages with contains the all the modules.
http://tenfouragency.com/setting-up-a-wamp-local-server-on-windows-7/

First, you'd need to create the DB in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/database-use.html

Second, you'd need to open it through webservices in Php: https://web.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_connect_to_a_MySQL_database_with_PHP

Third, you would need call your webservices through the app: http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/63338/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-an-iPhone-App-in-less-than-15-minutes

This is a fairly big endeavour for someone that's just starting out so I'd advise you just do these things one step at a time. This is also a very basic overview so I suggest you use the terms and concepts I use (such as webservices) to further your own research into these topics.